# compare certificate expiry date and time with current date and time in bash

Tags: command-line, server, bash, ssl

wanted to compare certification expiry date and time with current date and time. If current date and time exceeds certificate expiry date and time. i need to restart a service. through bash command.will iotedge system restart work directly in else statement.

```
openssl s_client -connect servername:443 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -dates | grep 'notAfter'
```

command gives certificate expiry date and time in format eg  Apr  9 04:57:28 2022 GMT with current date eg Fri Mar 11 05:11:21 UTC 2022

Comment: Read `man date`, you can output a date in any format, with the `+` option,  and can probably parse any format with `--date` option. Output each date as nanoseconds since the beginning of time to make arithmetic comparison easy

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the given date into a timestamp ([UNIX time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)) and then compare it with the current date and time in the same format:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# Your command goes in the parenthesis here
exp_date=$(echo 'Jan 9 04:57:28 2022 GMT')

exp_date_ut=$(date -d "$exp_date" +%s)
current_date_ut=$(date +%s)

if (( current_date_ut > exp_date_ut ))
then
    echo 'Do something...'
fi
```

References:

- [Unix&Linux: How to convert date to timestamp](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/310002/201297)